# Why is my object undefined when I try to print it when it is clearly defined?

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing the Codeacdemy tutorials on Javascript and while doing the Object tutorial I came I keep getting undefined for the following:

```
    // Our Person constructor
function Person (name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// Now we can make an array of people
var family = [];
family[0] = Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = Person("timmy", 6);

// loop through our new array
for(var person in family){
    console.log("name: "+person.name);
}
```

I have had issues with codecademy before so I tried it in my own webpage and still get undefined. Can anyone explain why to me. I have also tried  using `family[0].name` and that is undefined too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for-in loops return the index, not the value. If you change that to `console.log("name: "+family[person].name)`, it will work as expected.

```
for(var person in family){
    console.log(person);
    console.log("name: "+person.name);
}
0
name: undefined
1
name: undefined
2
name: undefined
3
name: undefined
```

As @basilikum also mentioned, you'll need to create each person with the `new` keyword, otherwise they won't be an object.

```
console.log(Person("alice", 40));     // undefined
console.log(new Person("alice", 40)); // Person {name: "alice", age: 40}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I've changed it to @basilikum accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.push()` to add new array members dynamically, so replacing your following code:

```
family[0] = Person("alice", 40);
```

for this one:

```
family.push( Person("alice", 40) );
```

Comment: You don't need to predefine the size in JS. It will let you set to family[4] without having 0-3 set, and it will expand the array to a length of 5, leaving anything you haven't defined as undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, need more coffee today, I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your objects using the `new` keyword:

```
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
```

`Person` is just a function. If you call it, you receive whatever this function returns. Since it doesn't return anything, all your entries are undefined. By using `new`, you are calling this function as a constructor, which creates an new objects with your defined properties and returns that object instead.

As SpenserJ said, you also have to keep in mind, that the `for` loop only returns the key and not the actual object.

Comment: this was actually one of the first things I tried, @SpenserJ solution worked without the `new` keyword

Comment: @jonnieM You definitely need the `new`. But your right, what SpenserJ said is also part of your problem.

Comment: sorry it appears you are right about the `new`, but codecadmey seems to not find an issue with that for some reason...

Comment: @jonnieM I'm sure what codeacademy does, but it is not wrong to write `family[0] = Person("alice", 40)`. This is perfectly valid JavaScript...it just doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A foreach loop in JavaScript provides the array key rather than value. By using `family[person].name` instead of `person.name`, the code should work.

Edit: The `new` keyword also seems to be missing from the `Person` creations.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried the **family[person].name** on the code academy exercise and it didn't work.

The thing about code academy is that they are looking for an answer SPECIFIC to what they have taught you so far.  My bf is a sr. software engineer and the .push tack would totally work in the every day coding world!  But they haven't taught us that yet.  So, when I plugged it in the code academy still didn't let me through.  lol.

Instead I did this:

```
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);


     for ( i = 0; i < family[4] ; i++ );

        console.log(family[0].name);
        console.log(family[1].name);
        console.log(family[2].name);
        console.log(family[3].name);
```

And it worked.... I'm sure there are other ways (hopefully shorter) to do this...